# Can I replace a 30A breaker in my panel with a 50A breaker (and new wiring)?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I need to add a 50 amp breaker to be used to supply a plug for EV charging.  My current panel is maxed out of spaces, however I do have a 30A breaker that is used for our Dryer that isn't currently being used as we have a LP gas dryer.

Is it safe to remove the current 30A breaker and replace with a 50A breaker?  Obviously there will be newer wires with the proper gauge running from the Nema outlet to the 50A breaker.  Assuming this is doable, what should be done with the Dryer wires that used to hook up to the 30A breaker?

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the panel?

Answer (score 1):

This is a DIY project we see a lot here. Yes, it's OK to remove your 30 Amp breaker and replace it with a 50 provided that's what your EV charger is calling for. Same for the wiring, what's called for in the installation manual. As far as the wires that used to go to the 30 Amp breaker, cut the tips off (Harper cringing), cap with a small wire nut, fold and tape them together and tuck them into the side of your panel. It's always nice to leave a note saying what the wires were for for a future homeowner or to just refresh your memory. Post a picture of your panel so if anything jumps out at us, we can further comment.

Comment: Ok but don’t snip, tape or wire nut and identity for future use (abandoned wires are supposed to be removed). +

Comment: @EdBeal  Wouldn't you want to leave them intact in case they wanted to shift back to the electric dryer? They're not really abandoned, just unused at the moment.

Comment: I mean to disconnect and insulate leave in the panel identified for future use. No snipping the ends. Just disconnecting is considered abandoned. I use white tape tape the ends and label where it goes At the other end I do the same. Inspectors have never flagged this I usually pull multiple spares into the attic or crawl space especially if the panel is in a visible area for future 2.50 per branch circuit for a spare can save 100$ later. (Fee for branch circuit on a new panel install).

Comment: @EdBeal  Great. That comma after snip threw me. Stay safe out there.

Comment: Thanks to all for answering. I will try and get some pictures posted later this evening.  Instead of removing the 30a breaker, is it possible to just use a quadbreaker like this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-Quadplex-One-Outer-50-Amp-Double-Pole-and-One-Inner-30-Amp-Double-Pole-Circuit-Breaker-Q23050CT2/202836168

Comment: @pip9ball  would need all your panel information to answer this.

Comment: Quad breakers can typically only be used in specific panels and often in specific spots IN the panels, that's why the full details would be required for an answer.

Comment: Here is a link to a photo of my panel.  https://photos.app.goo.gl/XS4ZyzvLwxizQRHq7. https://photos.app.goo.gl/uyHh8aqmUZnUxGdF8

Comment: @pip9ball  What is that 40 amp breaker at the bottom?  Is it live or on a spare slot?

Comment: Right now it's not connected, but that is because my solar installation AC lines have not been ran yet. Later this week it will be connected.